# How to fix the PlotRange on LogPlot?

Tags: plotting, manipulate, distributions, logarithmic-scale

I'm plotting families of [Boltzmann](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_distribution)'esque distribution functions $\propto\exp\left(-{\dfrac{\varepsilon+{\mathcal O}(\varepsilon^2)}{k_\mathrm{B} T}}\right)$.

But it won't let me fix the `PlotRange` as I vary the parameter $x$ using `Manipulate`. How to fix this?

I tried to wrap it into a `Show` somehow and overwrite the changing range, but that didn't work. I'm using *Mathematica* 6.

```
Manipulate[
    LogPlot[
        Table[
            Exp[-(En + x En^2)/kT] 2 kT^(-3/2)/Sqrt[Pi], 
            {kT, 8, 3, -1}
        ],{En, 0, 30}, PlotRange -> {0, 0.2}
    ],{x, 0, 3}]
```

Comment: Try `PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, {10^-5, 1}}` or `PlotRange -> {All, {10^-5, 1}}`. The problem is `0`.

Comment: @Thanks Kuba, that worked.